# The expression prefix 'App_GlobalResources' was not recognized. Please correct the prefix or register the prefix in the

Tags: asp.net, sharepoint, localization, prefix

I have a App_GlobalResources in my solution that have a few resx files.

In my ASPX page I am recieving a error when I type:

```
<asp:Label ID="label" runat="server" Text="<% $App_GlobalResources:Portal.Localization.Global, Navigation_Organization%>"></asp:Label>
```

The error is following:

> The expression prefix 'App_GlobalResources' was not recognized. 
>   Please correct the prefix or register the prefix in the
>    section of configuration.

I have no idea why I am recieving this error, anyone had similiar problems?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try the following instead in your Label:

```
Text="<%$ Resources: Portal.Localization.Global, Navigation_Organization %>"
```